# Interesting application of mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, differentiable on $(a, b)$ and satisfies$$ f^2(a)−f^2(b)= a^2−b^2$$Then show that the equation $f′(x)f(x) = x$ has at least one root in $(a, b)$.

Comment: How to proceed any hints  help

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Consider the function
$F(x):=\frac{1}{2}(f^2(x)-x^2)$
and apply Rolle's Theorem with respect to the interval $[a,b]$.